# How to optimize erasing from multimap

Tags: c++

I have two multimaps defined so multimap phoneNums; and multimap numPhones; they are some kind of phone registry - phoneNums contains Key name, and second argument phonenumber, numPhones contain Key phonenumber and second is name. I want to optimize erase from both of them when i want to delete string Key form phoneNums, which is also second element in numPhones. When i enter data it is entered in both multimaps so they are actually the same but with swapped first and second
when i put it on tests it says that erasing is too slow - N*N and must be only N

```
cin>>stringToErase;
                    phoneNums.erase(stringToErase);
                    multimap<string, string>::iterator it;
                    multimap<string, string>::iterator tmpr;
                    for(it = numPhones.begin(); it != numPhones.end();it++)
                    {

                        if(it->second == tringToErase)
                        {   
                            tmpr = it;      
                            numPhones.erase(it,tmpr);                           
                        }                       
                    }
```

Comment: Are you asking us to give you the answer to a homework or interview question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, for this kind of problem, you can use the following technic:

- A container, which holds the data
- Several indexes, which point to the data aforementioned

If you place reverse indexes along the data (so as to point to the places in the indexes that refer to this item), then you can efficiently remove any item:

- Look it up using the most suitable index (depending on the info you have)
- Delete the references in the various indexes (you have iterators to them, so it's efficient)
- Delete the data itself

This may seem tedious, but it's what [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) is for :)

For the very specific case you are speaking of, there is a wrapper above the MultiIndex library called [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) as mentioned by `Jack`.

Comment: Are map iterators guaranteed to be stable across insertion and deletion?  Would that also be true of a hashmap?

For me the general solution would be to use the data to look the item up in the other indexes and delete them there.

Comment: `list`, `map` and `set` provide stability: the iterator is valid until deletion of the element it points to. For the `unordered_map` I have no idea of the guarantees the standard impose. Would be worth consulting the Final Draft I guess. As for looking once again... it isn't as efficient. So perhaps a distinguished approach (depending on the index underlying type) would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Why didn't you use a more suitable/specific data structure for your problem like a **Bimap**?

Boost has [one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)..